# Get selected features on ArcMap in arcMap Addin (eclipse)

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-desktop, java, eclipse

I am building a custom arcMap Addin button which onclick event tells info about selected features.

Following is my java class ---

```
public class Break extends Button {

/**
 * Called when the button is clicked.
 * 
 * @exception java.io.IOException if there are interop problems.
 * @exception com.esri.arcgis.interop.AutomationException if the component throws an ArcObjects exception.
 */
@Override
public void onClick() throws IOException, AutomationException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    MapBean mapBean = new MapBean();
    try{
        IMap map = mapBean.getMap();
        ISelection selection = map.getFeatureSelection();
        IEnumFeature enumFeature = (IEnumFeature)selection;
        enumFeature.reset();
        IFeature feature = enumFeature.next();
        while (feature != null){
            System.out.println("FEATURE ID: " + feature.getOID());
            feature = enumFeature.next();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

I implimented the button on ArcMap but nothing seems to work onclick event , might be its not getting the ArcMap at all.Could anybody tell how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance////

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew Rohne is correct, you first need to get reference to the application then the mxdoc within your click event method.  Here is an example below (in vb.net though):

```
Public Shared gApp As IApplication
Public Shared gMxDoc As IMxDocument

 Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
        Try
            gApp = CType(Hook, IApplication)
            gMxDoc = CType(My.ArcMap.Application.Document, IMxDocument)

            'your logic here

            My.ArcMap.Application.CurrentTool = Nothing

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Caught an unspecified error in the calling code: " & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
        End Try
 Emd Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have:

```
@Override
public void init(IApplication app) throws IOException, AutomationException {
    this.app = app;
    super.init(app);
}
```

In your class?

You would need to have an application object in the class:

```
public class Break extends Button {
    private IApplication app; //<~ Add this too
    @Override
    public void onClick() throws IOException, AutomationException {
```